# Getting all available packages to install

Tags: package-management

I need to see all the packages that are available to install via a command so I can use it in another program. I tried `dpkg -l` but it only gives the installed packages. The output is like this:

> ii  apache2-utils 2.2.22-1ubuntu1 utility programs for webservers

It is so similar to Synaptic output, so is there a common command like this am I missing? `apt-cache` is helpful but not it is not in the above format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 day of searching it I found:

```
aptitude search ^
```

Quite a big list though.